# I am trying to copy a entire website e-commerce system locally, How do i do it?

Tags: php, wordpress, git, magento, netbeans

I have trying to download a whole working e - commerce website. I keep getting stuck.
Its a website using Magento + Wordpress.

1. I have installed XAMPP.
2. I have run Apache, and PHP
3. I have created a DB called magento.
4. When I go on to localhost/websitetest
5. Magento installation process starts, instead of loading the full working website, even though it
   doesnt have any data in the DB's, it should still run perfectly right?

First big tasks I am attempting at this.

I downloaded all the files as instructed by the admin of the website using git. He mentioned something of running a remote project using Netbeans possibly. What other solutions or alternatives are there?

Comment: Although I haven't worked with Magento I imagine that you should backup your data(db) from the remote website and then apply the backup locally. All the products and in general content of the website is saved there so even if you create a database it will still be empty so you will have an empty site :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overview
Here is an overview of the steps we’ll take to do this:

1. Make a MySQL dump file of the database
2. Archive the media and theme directories
3. Copy the files to the other server
4. Install a clean version of Magento
5. Import the dump file to a blank database
6. Move our copied data to the correct places

If you follow the instructions on their webpage it should not be a problem ([Moving Magento to a new server](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/moving_magento_to_another_server)

Hope everything goes well, good luck!